# How to remove pages from stack using Navigator.pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I'm trying to understand Navigator 2.0 Pages API which allows to modify navigation stack via [Navigator.pages](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pages.html) property.

I prepared simple demo where I try to remove pages from the backstack by updating the provided list of pages.

[Here is the DartPad demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3155332097b7c691e2b9cdaa1ac620a0)

[image: screen recording of the issue]

However, when simply removing the `CustomPage` from the [Navigator.pages](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pages.html) there's an animation glitch. For a split second you can see the page being animated beneath the current page.

Is it a bug in Flutter framework or is there a better way to remove pages from the backstack?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `ValueKey` to the `Navigator` widget seems to solve the problem:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Navigator Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Navigator(
        key: ValueKey(pages.length), // <------------- 
        pages: List.unmodifiable(pages),
        onPopPage: _onPopPage,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solved the problem! Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not a workaround or a even a good idea. You will loose your entire sub-tree state of all your routes.

Comment: That's correct, state will be lost and keys will be different on each pages change